# Using sed command to find and replace code

Tags: sed, find

I have a block of php code (inside `<? php ... ?>`) in multiple files which I want to remove.

I tried to put the code into a variable:

```
var="<?php [some code in here] ?>"
```

Then run this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed "s|$var| |" {} \;
```

Or

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/'"$var"'.*/'"$str"'/g' {} \;
```

(where str=" ")

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You got success and looking for another way(s)? or you couldn't get success with above ones? BTW both working just fine

Comment: Somehow none of the above works for me. :( None of them could replace the string.

Comment: Is this on one line, or multiple? Are there special characters in the php element (relative to bash; `$`, `!`, `"`, `'`)?

Comment: You'll also run in trouble if your php code contains `/` or `.` or `[` or `*` or something else that breaks your `sed` script. We could better help you if you tell us the actual code to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but remove the `-i` the first time to make sure it works:

```
var='echo rand(1, 10);'  # dummy code, change to whatever.
sed -i 's/<? php '"${var}"' ?>//' *.php
```

Notes:

- The code in `$var` is assumed to be a one-liner.
- If the code contains any `'` single quotes, escape them like so `\'`.
- The above assumes whitespace variation isn't a problem, but it often can be.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But what I mean is there are more code in that "....". My bad not making it clear.